Why use rtnl_lock when making changes on a network interface in the linux kernel?
I have a somewhat silly question but I was wondering why do we need to serialize the operations concerning changes to a specific interface ? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10-rc7/source/net/core/dev_ioctl.c#L764
Couldn't we perform changes to two different interfaces at the same time without a problem ?
This question was born because I am facing a similar issue like the one described here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/scale-register-a-network-device-register_netdev-takes-long-time-and-high-cpu-usage-4175725384/
